# Possible to prevent Camel routes shutdown during spring refresh event

Tags: apache-camel, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have been trying to integrate the Spring Cloud Ribbon client into my camel routes with no luck. Apparently the Ribbon client performs an application context refresh during which the Camel context is restarted. For reference: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/438#issuecomment-121282986

I'm looking for a way to prevent Camel from tearing down during these refreshes, or any other solution that prevents such a painful pause. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try configure CamelContext to not shutdown eager, by setting `shutdownEager=false` on the `SpringCamelContext`.

However it depends on which events Spring emits, you can set DEUBG logging on `org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext` and see what events are emitted. The shutdown eager with false will not stop Camel on `ContextClosedEvent` which is maybe what you need.

Comment: This didn't work. Logging didn't show any event being emitted either.